# Loading into Array causes Stack Smashing while having enough space?

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx, avx512, stack-smash

When executing the following code I get a `Stack Smashing` error.

```
const uint size = 62;

...
for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i){
    // mask = elements != zero
    // input = epi32 m512 data containing 1 byte values
    _mm512_mask_compress_epi32(input, mask, input);
    // get just elements != 0 as previous mask. 
    __mmask16 mask1 = _mm512_cmpneq_epi32_mask(compressed, _mm512_setzero_epi32());
    // append the non-zero elements to the uchar* 
    _mm512_mask_cvtusepi32_storeu_epi8((uchar*)str+pos, mask1, compressed); // uncommenting = no error, truncating mask = no error

     // add size of the inserted elements by counting 1's in mask
     pos += sizeOfInsertion;

     // print the position of the pointer AFTER storing
     void* pp = (void*) ((uchar*) str + pos);
     std::cout << pp << std::endl;
}
```

To investigate this issue, I was checking the position of the pointer while inserting the elements.
At beginning `(pointing to str[0])` I have `0x7ffce3468d30`, at the end `0x7ffce3468d69`. Subtracting these addresses I get `3E = 62`. So it should fit inside the declared array.
Shifting the mask by 1 (truncating one element), it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: This code doesn't show how you calculate `sizeOfInsertion`, or any variables, or how you produce `compressed`.  i.e. it's lacking a [mcve].  Also, if your answer does somehow answer the question, why are you re-calculating a mask after `vpcompressd`?  Can't you just use the existing `__mask16` that you used for left-packing, to feed your narrowing?  Also, AVX512 has ways to test elements for zero/non-zero without comparing against a zeroed register.  e.g. `mask = _mm512_test_epi32_mask(same,same)`

Comment: you should add the missing parts to the problem so people can see everything @Sapp

Comment: thanks, I just added some additional explanations. The recalculation is because data in the input data doesn't need to be contigous, so the mask could be like `1100 0110 0101 0011`. After compression the data is contiguous, so the mask would be like `1111 1111 0000 0000`. Thanks for the hint using `_mm512_test_epi32_mask`.

Comment: Oh right, yeah you would need to left-pack or recompute the mask.  Or you could just do unmasked partially-overlapping 128-bit stores, if you can pad your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure was in the compression. I didn't mind zeroing the values not matching the mask, so data wasn't stored contiguously and the stack was therefore overflowing.

In short:

```
_mm512_maskz_compress_epi32(mask, input);
```

made it work.

Comment: You don't need to merge-mask into a zeroed register, you can just use `_mm512_maskz_compress_epi32` to do zero-masking instead of merge-masking.  (Or even `_mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi32` to do a masked store into memory).

Comment: Thanks, just changed it as you suggested.